# SQL Server database restore for quick testing

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have a big database which takes few minutes to restore from a bak file. I have to run few tests using a web application, and then discard all those changes for repeating the tests. This is the workflow I am currently doing, and my question is that is there a better/less time consuming method.

1. Restore db from a bak file (bak file is ~5gb and takes around 1 minute)
2. Perform testing using a web application.
3. Drop the database, and restore it again afresh from the bak file (step 1)

The db restore option takes a lot of time, I was thinking if I can use something like `CHECKPOINTS`, or some other feature where I don't have to restore the full backup again.

**Edit**: I would like to know if solutions exist where we can reduce the restore time using a in-built sql-server feature. Imagine if the restore takes 5 minutes, - whether 5 minutes is a **long time** or a **short time** is relative to each user and each use-case.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. It seems more like you're asking how to perform tests.

Comment: Step 1 says it takes around 1 minute to restore the db. Then you say it takes a long time to do the db restore option. Either you are contradicting yourself or you think that 1 minute takes a long time. This is all the part of testing.

Comment: 1 minute is a long time if you are testing it repeatedly. I would greatly appreciate if the focus was on the concept to restore a db without the full restore. Thank you.

Comment: This is definitely an X/Y problem. I'm going to go out on a limb and guess you don't need 5gb of compressed data to run a few tests. Run your tests and then roll them back instead of deleting the whole db.

Comment: @Sekhar You need to be clear on what you are asking. Are you looking for the fastest mechanism to restore a database, or are you looking for a way to reset the changes done to a database during testing? If you make one update to one field in one row for one person through your application and then throw the whole db away, that is a silly testing mechanism.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear.. I actually want to reset the changes done to a database during testing.

Comment: Agreed that this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) but to answer the question, NO. You can't restore a database without restoring the database. You will have to restore the database again if you want it in a certain state.

Comment: You could try a [snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server). Reverting to those is faster. They used to be Enterprise only, but it seems that in 2017 they're available in all editions (and even then there's always Developer if not). A better approach is still to reduce the database to a minimal form for testing, using an SSDT database project to distribute that right along with your source. If you must have ALL the data, a persistent staging environment (that you need not revert every time) is probably better.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Excellent!!! Snapshots is what I was looking for!! The snapshot-restore takes just 3 seconds now :)  I will accept your comment as answer if you can post it as an answer.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I took the liberty of opining why I think the alternatives are better. I hope you don't mind. :-P

Comment: Sure.. more knowledge and more approaches are always welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, "I have an enormous database with all the data that I run a few tests against and revert after every test" is not, in the long run, a very good pattern in my experience -- there's still the matter of getting that enormous database first somewhere (you don't want to use *production*, do you?), possible issues with people not being allowed to see the data, concurrency issues if the instance is shared, and the most damning, brittle tests that rely on specific data being present. Look away for two weeks and you find your tests no longer work and people can't say why.

The best long-term solution is to create a minimal database project using [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt), which serves as something you can check into source control to boot. Deploy as a LocalDB, insert only data needed for your test, test, then discard it. No dependencies, no hidden assumptions.

Having said that, SQL Server does offer [database snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server), created with [`CREATE DATABASE ... AS SNAPSHOT OF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql) and reverted to with [`RESTORE DATABASE ... FROM SNAPSHOT = ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/revert-a-database-to-a-database-snapshot). As this only involves discarding modified data, it can be much faster than a full restore. It still inevitably suffers from concurrency issues if multiple people want to run tests.